# Is there a way to get the Code Mirror editor in Google Chrome developer tools to use a specific keymap?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, codemirror

Google Chrome now supports using [the CodeMirror editor](http://codemirror.net/) instead of its old editor in developer tools. You can turn it on by going to developer tools settings and checking “use code mirror editor”.

While this is very cool, I would like to use it with a certain keymap, specifically the vim one, which [Code Mirror supports](http://codemirror.net/demo/vim.html). I am wondering whether there is a way to hack it to load vim.js into the developer tools context. I have tried looking in the folder where Chrome is installed on my machine, but I could not find where it does its thing.

Apparently, Chrome loads the CodeMirror stuff from `chrome-devtools://devtools/CodeMirrorTextEditor.js`, which seems to come from the resources.pak file in the Chrome install directory, but making changes to that file does not seem to have an effect. Maybe I am not refreshing things property, or maybe you’re not supposed to edit the pak file directly.

Comment: there's no way to 'hack' it, you'd have to alter the sources and  recompile chromium for that

Comment: There's actually a way to use custom DevTools front-end for debugging via the combination of chrome runtime flags `--remote-debugging-port` and `--remote-debugging-frontend`. This way you'll still need to hack on DevTools sources, but you'll avoid checking out and compiling the whole chromium project - this takes *a lot*. More on this could be found here: https://medium.com/p/8c8896f5cef3